# TensorFlow image classification colab sheet from training material: newbie questions

Tags: google-colaboratory

Apologies if my questions are relatively simple, but I have been approaching the TensorFlow bit recently with the aim to learn new skills. 
In the [example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l03c01_classifying_images_of_clothing.ipynb#scrollTo=_FxXYSCXGQqQ), but there are several things I can't get:

- in the explore data section, the size of the datasets return as 60/10k respectively for train and test.

  - where the size of the train/test size declared?
  - packages like SkLearn allows this to be specified in percentage when invoking the split methods.
- in the training model part, when the 5 epochs are trained, the 1875 number appear below.

[image]
  - what is that? 
  - I was expecting the training to run over the 60k items, but even by multiplying 1875 by 5 the number doesn't reach the 10k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Dataset is loaded using tensorflow datasets API
   [image]

The source itself has the split of 60K (Train) and 10K (Test)
https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/fashion_mnist

2. An Epoch is a complete run with all the training samples. The training is done in batches. In the example you refer to, a batch size of 32 is used. So to complete one epoch, 1875 batches (60000 / 32) are run.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @James. So basically everything that is within the tf.keras.Sequential([...]) is my model, repeated 1 time for each image per the number of times of my epoch. Correct?